# ajax post multiple values for mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got this ajax code that passes one variable for a mysql query. I need to pass an other variable. I already got the variable, but i don't know how to add it to the existing code.

this is the code

```
function Docent(){

var opleidingid = $('#opleidingddl').val();
var datum = $('#datumddl :selected').text();

$('#docentddl').html();
$('#docentddl').html("<option>Loading.....</option>");
$.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"Docent.php"
       data :
       {
       'opleidingid': opleidingid,
       'datum'      : datum
       },
       success: function(data){
       $('#docentddl').html();
       $('#docentddl').html("<option value='0'>Selecteer docent</option>");
       $.each(data,function(i,item){
              $('#docentddl').append('<option value="'+ data[i].Opleiding_ID +'">'+ data[i].Docent+'</option>');
              $('#docentddl').selectpicker('refresh');
              });
       },
       complete: function(){
       }
       });

 }
```

PHP

```
<?php

include ('config.php');

$opleidingid    = $_POST['opleidingid'];
$datum        = $_POST['datum'];


$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Docent_relatie WHERE Opleiding_ID = 'opleidingid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $data = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[] = array(
                        'Opleiding_ID' => $row['Opleiding_ID'],
                        'Docent' => $row['Docent'],
                        'OpleidingDatum' => $row['OpleidingDatum']
                        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Comment: Use the url as it is... an url and set ajax method post or get. Use data: in you ajax to pass whatever you want. Example: data: {id: sid, var1:var1

Comment: That's exactly what i tried, but i can't  get it right. I don't know how to use the post method and still get the right query for the #docentddl.

Comment: type:"post", url:"Docent.php", data:{var1: var1, var2:var2}. Delete dataType and contentType. In PHP $_POST('var1') , $_POST('var2').

Comment: Also use html('blabla') instead of empty plus append . This replace it all. Then append in the each is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've tried it, but i still can't get it to work. I.ve updated my code and add the php code.

Comment: Remove header from your php. Add var result=JSON.parse(data) in the ajax success as you have encoded it it php (this is the way to go). Use result for your $.each loop. ;-)

Comment: Keep the header in PHP, just add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call

Comment: No. You (supposedly) allready have a header as html in your metatype, keep it. Dont send a new header. Totaly useless with ajax. Datatype is totaly useless too in this case. Like in 99.99% of real live cases. Ajax send a json and you encode/decode a json for the response. Another way would be to stringify your ajax data and decode it in php. That s all you need.

Answer (score 1):

ok. so I am back to my computer.
It should look like something like this.
One important comment. 
you **DO NOT** want to use mysql deprecated method.

you **DO WANT** to use PDO instead of mysql or mysqli.

**Follow this rule, always:**

PDO uses prepared statment that can be reused at will.

1: you prepare the statment using ? per values.

2: you bind the values (by order of appearance in the query, 1,2,3....)

3: you execute the statement.

4: you use a foreach loop to go across the result array, not a while.

To be noted. In PHP, the foreach loop across the result is a redundancy.
You can simply directly echo $result and deal with it in javascript (in this case, in the query, instead of select *, select Opleiding_ID,Docent,OpleidingDatum but I did not wanted to "modify" your logic.

Javascript:

```
function Docent() {
var opleidingid = $('#opleidingddl').val();
var datum = $('#datumddl :selected').text();

$('#docentddl').html("<option>Loading.....</option>");
var datas = {'opleidingid': opleidingid, 'datum': datum};

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "Docent.php",
    data: datas,
    success: function (data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (result.ctrl === true) {
                $('#docentddl').html("<option value='0'>Selecteer docent</option>");
                $.each(result.response, function (i, item) {
                    $('#docentddl').append('<option value="' + item.Opleiding_ID + '">' + item.Docent + '</option>');
                });
                $('#docentddl').selectpicker('refresh');
        }else{
            alert(result.response);// error message from php
        }
    }
});
```

}

PHP:

```
define("SQLHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("SQLDB", "databasename");
define("SQLUSER", "login");
define("SQLPASS", "password");
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLDB . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Docent_relatie WHERE Opleiding_ID = ? AND datum= ?");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(['ctrl' => false, 'response' => 'Connection failed to the database: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
}
$opleidingid = (isset($_POST['opleidingid'])) ? $_POST['opleidingid'] : null; // control if ajax sent proper value
$datum = (isset($_POST['datum'])) ? $_POST['datum'] : null; // control if ajax sent proper value
if ($opleidingid !== null && $datum !== null) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $opleidingid, PDO::PARAM_INT); // could be PARAM_STR depending if $opleidingid is a int or a string
    $stmt->bindParam(2, datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data = array();
    if (count($result) !== 0) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
            $data[] = array(
                'Opleiding_ID' => $row['Opleiding_ID'],
                'Docent' => $row['Docent'],
                'OpleidingDatum' => $row['OpleidingDatum']
            );
        }
        echo json_encode(['ctrl' => true, 'response' => $data]);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(['ctrl' => false, 'response' => 'No results found']);   
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['ctrl' => false, 'response' => 'ajax did not send values']);
}
```